# require asssistnce on PHP function call handler

Tags: php

I want to use the `function getdetails ($uid){}` to gather user data. Where `$uid` is a Variable which has a value of `$_SESSION['uid'];`. Simply what I'm trying to do is to gather `userName,` `firstName`and `email`using the `$uid`.

I'm new to php functions and so any assistance will be highly appreciated.

Comment: You dont need `$uid` as a parameter because it's stored in `session` so you can use session globally in every file.

Comment: And your question is...............?

Comment: i want expalanation on how i can implement that function `function getdetails ($uid){}`to gather the user data from database.

Comment: Store `userName`, `firstName` and `email` in `$_SESSION` as well

Comment: Do you already have a `Database`

Comment: I think you are asking about database driven programming using PHP. For better understanding you can have look on this tutorial. http://buildinternet.com/2009/12/creating-your-first-php-application-part-1/. Or you can simply Google php database driven application you will get n number of sample code to check.

Comment: @MattMagallo i already have the `$_SESSION['uid'];`. And so i feel like it is safe to  store all user data in a session and there4 i wanted to define a `custom function` for pulling off that data. The function of which i will include in all in multiple files as per requirement.

Comment: @LittlePhild I have a `database myUsers` with table `users` which contain columns `id,  userName, firstName and email`

Comment: If you want to fetch that data from the database through the function then use the below answer that i have posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$uid = $_SESSION['uid'];
$firstName = $_SESSION['firstName'];
$email= $_SESSION['email'];

function getdetails ($uid, $firstName, $email){
   return "Name: ".$firstName."<br />Email: ".$email;
}

echo getdetails();
```

Try this.

**OR**

```
function getdetails($uid = 1, $firstName = "Matt", $email = "asd@email.com"){
    return "Name: ".$firstName."<br />Email: ".$email;
}

echo getdetails();
```

Comment: Echoing inside a function:  Isn't this bad practice/poor coding style ?. I would say functions should always return and then echo when calling  it

Comment: Works for me with no problem, 4+6=10 and 2+8=10 IDK how'd you do it on your own perspective. the OP needs a brief and easy explanation and not to complicate things for the OP. I guess i have to stick for on my answer.

Comment: your answer works perfect but to some people like @Nicolas who is just beginning `PHP` i would highly dismiss your coding style. Bse he will grow with that habit over and over

Comment: I'll just tidy that one up, i know its messy LOL thank you for that @LittlePhild, and sorry XD

Comment: Thanks for understanding  +1

Comment: My bad ^^, No worries.

Comment: Okay, What seems to be the problem @Nicholas

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103828/discussion-between-matt-magallo-and-little-phild).

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
function getdetails($uid){
   $query = mysql_query("SELECT u.`userName`,u.`firstName`, u.`email` from `users` u where u.`id`= '{$uid}' ");
   $user_data = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
   return $user_data;
}
```

Then you can call your function wherever you want

such as

```
$user_id = $_SESSION['uid'];
$user_data = getdetails($user_id);
print_r($user_data);
```

Answer (score 0):

on that questions this is what i was looking for.
`function getdetails ($userID)
    {

    $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=$userID";`

```
$result = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($query));

return $result['firstname'] . ' ' .$result['surname'];  

}
`
```

Anyway thank you guys the offering some help..